# Code Generation in Clojure

Tags: clojure

(Disclaimer: I am a C# guy. I've just started learning Clojure.)

I understand that a Clojure *program* has the ability to manipulate itself or easily generate other *programs*. It has something to do with everything in Clojure being a data structure and that generating *programs* would be the same as creating any other type of data structure.

Does anybody have a good sample program (or a reference to one) that shows this?

If you generate a *program*, can you "serialize" that program out to disk for later execution?

Just for reference:

1. I'm trying to play with Genetic Programming. I want to generate a lot of little programs, evaluate them, and use the successful ones to generate more programs. See more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming) and [here](http://www.genetic-programming.org/).
2. I think I'm misusing terms here. By *program* I actually mean a clojure list and by *Code Generation* I mean "List Generation". I just need the list to contain actual function calls and parameters. I would need to be able to control when this list gets "executed".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Consider `(+ 1 2)`.  As data, it's a linked list of three items: the Symbol `+` and two Integers.  As code, it's a function call, saying "Call the function called `+` with these two Integers as arguments and give me the result".  You can do anything to this list that you can do to any other list of data.  You can also `eval` it to get a result.

```
user> (def x '(+ 1 2))
#'user/x
user> (first x)
+
user> (rest x)
(1 2)
user> (map class x)
(clojure.lang.Symbol java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer)
user> (reverse x)
(2 1 +)
user> (concat x (rest x))
(+ 1 2 1 2)
user> (eval x)
3
user> (defn foo []
        (let [ops '[+ - * /]               ; SO's lisp-highlighting sucks
              nums (repeatedly #(rand-int 5))
              expr (list* (rand-elt ops) (take 10 nums))]
          (prn expr)
          (prn (eval expr))))
user> (foo)
(+ 4 1 0 3 2 3 4 3 1 2)
23
nil
user> (foo)
(- 1 3 2 2 1 2 1 4 0 1)
-15
nil
```

Answer (score 5):

Clojure is a LISP, and that means that it is a [homoiconic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) language:  there is no structural distinction between data and code.  Its lists all the way down.  It also has an extensible compiler which allows you to extend the syntax through macros.  But its not clear from your problem statement that you really need such a thing.

You're basically running code that generates lists (which are really next gen programs), saving them, and then running the new programs.  Unless your generational evolution will require new syntax, you probably wouldn't need to resort to macros.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after! If I understand correctly, each "program" is going to be a list. I just need a way to "generate" that list with function calls and parameters and then "execute" that list once I'm done. I think I just need to generate the list prefixed by a quote, so that the list isn't "evaluated".

Comment: Exactly.  You'll want to read and understand this page: http://clojure.org/reader

Answer (score 4):

Found a partial answer in [this](http://java.ociweb.com/mark/clojure/article.html) article:

> The `pr` and `prn` functions are like
>   their print and println counterparts,
>   but their output is in a form that can
>   be read by the Clojure reader. They
>   are suitable for serializing Clojure
>   data structures. By default, they do
>   not print metadata. This can be
>   changed by binding the special symbol
>   `*print-meta*` to `true`.

This at least answers the second part of my question.

Answer (score 3):

The question is somewhat misleading as Clojure also performs on-the-fly "code generation" as it compiles Clojure source in Java Byte Code.

In this particular case, *I believe* you are interesting in Lisp Macros in particular. I think these may be interesting:

[Clojure documentation itself](http://clojure.org/macros)

[Video, Macros (in Clojure) in 20 minutes](http://www.slideshare.net/pcalcado/lisp-macros-in-20-minutes-featuring-clojure-presentation)

[Standard issue: Wikipedia - Clojure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure)

Note that macros in Clojure work *very similar* to Common Lisp macros (a type-2 lisp), and not quite-so-much-like Scheme macros.

Happy coding.

Comment: Remember, I'm a C# guy. I am most definitely misusing the term "Code Generation" here. I think what I'm really trying to say is "List Generation", but the list needs to contain actual function calls.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at macros.  For example,

```
(defmacro defmacro-
  "Same as defmacro but yields a private definition"
  [name & decls]
  (list* `defmacro (with-meta name (assoc (meta name) :private true)) decls))
```

With macros, you don't need to serialize out the macroexpansion; the compile will use it automatically.